# Customizing ListView to show Image along with CheckedTextView in the same row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I've the following row.XML to display checkbox in list view. Now, I want to add an Image and some text in the same row along with checkbox. How can I do this?

row.xml

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Comment: Do you have the image how your code should give the output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/yourImage" />

<CheckedTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Foo"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it won't work without a custom adapter. do you have example code for custom adapter?

Comment: no worries. i figured out the custom adapter code. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @codebringer using this does not let me select the checkbox. What do you think is the problem. FYI using a listFragment

Comment: @bianca are you able to select the checkbox by using imageView and checkedTV in the linearLayout

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create a RelativeLayout that contains all of the items you want to show in each row and a custom adapter that will allow you to populate the ListView with the rows.